# How to find words having given letter using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

```
public class Homework {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String words[] = { "Abendessen", "Affe", "Affen", "aber", "anders", "Attacke", "arrangieren", "Art", "Asien",
            "Bund", "Arten", "Biene", "Abend", "baden", "suchen", "A1rten", "Abend-Essen" };

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[aA][a-z[n]+a-z]*");

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(words[i]);
      if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("OK: " + words[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Filters for words beginning with a or A and having an n in the word. These words may only consist of letters and have only small letters starting with the second letter.
These words should be matched: Abendessen, Affen, anders, arrangieren, Asien, Arten, Abend

I've tried this regular expression above carelessly and believe that's wrong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current pattern `[aA][a-z[n]+a-z]*` reads as:

Character class `[aA]`, character class `[a-z[n]+`. It is then followed by `a-z]*` which will match an `a`, `-`, `z` and `]` repeated 0+ times.

That would for example match `Abendessena-z]`

What you might do is to start the match with a or A and repeat 2 times `[a-z]` 0+ times and make sure that there is a `n` in the middle:

```
\b[aA][a-z]*n[a-z]*\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[aA]` Match a or A
- `[a-z]*` Match 0+ times a-z
- `n` Match `n`
- `[a-z]*` Match 0+ times a-z
- `\b` Word boundary

You might also use anchors `^` and `$` to assert that start and the end of the string instead of `\b`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vw16aH/1)

Comment: Wow thanks for your fast and furious answer :D I used ^ and $ instead of \b, because with \b the word "Abend-Essen" matched too

Comment: @AnhMinhNguyễn That would also match. That pattern would look like `^[aA][a-z]*n[a-z]*$`